# Python list.index function with random probability on collision

Tags: python, arrays, random

Let's say I have a list: `a = [1,1]`.

If I call `a.index(1)` it will always return `0`.

Is there any pythonic way to return `0` or `1` in equal probabilities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list) Then [How can I randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306400/843953)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting random elements in a list conditional on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695580/selecting-random-elements-in-a-list-conditional-on-attribute) Or with numpy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798508/get-random-element-on-condition

Answer (score -1):

As stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

The syntax of the index method is: `list.index(x[, start[, end]])`.

It also says:

> The optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in the slice notation and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the start argument.

So a possible way could be the use of random as the `start` argument:

```
import random

a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

index_method = a.index(1)
index_method_with_start = a.index(1, random.randint(0, len(a) -1))

print(index_method, index_method_with_start)
```

Comment: Interesting idea, however this means that it will randomly raise ValueError if all instances of the target value are before the random start index.

Comment: And it's biased.

Comment: @KellyBundy Could you explain why?

Comment: For example if `a = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`, the second `1` is more likely than the first.

Comment: Is there a feasible way to do it?

Comment: @Kyostenas the less perfomatic way to do this that I've found was this: `np.random.choice(np.where(v == v.max())`